# Conversion Calculations With Array

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface

I am creating a conversion calculator for distances between various cities. But I am having a problem with how to call the calculations from the conversion method. Such as here:

```
private class ComboBoxListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        int selectedRow = destinationBox.getSelectedIndex();
        int selectedCol = originBox.getSelectedIndex();
        distanceText.setText(fileData[selectedRow + 1][selectedCol + 1]);
    }
}

private class RadioButtonListener implements ActionListener
{

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getSource() == kilometersRadioButton)
        {
            distanceLabel.setText("Distance (kilometers):");
            avgspeedLabel.setText("Avg. Speeg (kph): ");  
        }
        else if (event.getSource() == milesRadioButton)
        {
            distanceLabel.setText("Distance (miles): ");
            avgspeedLabel.setText("Avg. Speeg (mph): ");
        }
    }
}
```

This part is where the 2D array selects the value and my intent is to have the calculation from miles to KM occur whenever the radio buttons are clicked. The file I am drawing from is in miles by default.

```
public class MetricConverter
{

    public static double milesToKilometers(double miles) //This static method holds the miles to kilometers conversion equation
    {
        return miles * 1.609;
    }

    public static double kilometersToMiles(double kilometers) //This static method holds the kilometers to miles conversion equation
    {
        return kilometers / 1.609;
    }
}
```

This is the conversion method. How do I call them as the values of the array are in a TextField/String.

Thank You,

Comment: I'm still having a bit of trouble with this. When I call for the calculation, I want to do it under the actionPerformed method when the radio buttons are clicked. The textfield will initially populate after the cities are selected. But there's something I am misunderstanding about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you know how to call the conversion method. Consider this scenario:

1. You select two cities. The distance is shown in miles.
2. You select kilometer. The distance is shown in kilometers.
3. You change one of the cities. **The distance is shown in miles, even though the radio button 'kilometers' is selected.**

Problem is that the text you write in `distanceText` depends on two different input actions: setting the cities and setting the display type. Therefore, you need all that information when you set the text.

Assuming that your event handlers are declared as inner classes, I propose some fields for that data, corresponding setters, and an "update text" method:

```
private int row, column;
private boolean inKm;

private void setCities(int row, int column) {
    this.row = row;
    this.column = column;
}

private void setKm(boolean inKm) {
    this.inKm = inKm;
}

// one place to set the distance text
private void updateDistanceText() {
    String text = fileData[row+1][column+1];
    if (inKm) {
        text = String.valueOf(
                   MetricConverter.milesToKilometers(Double.valueOf(text)));
    }
    distanceText.setText(text);        
}
```

Finally, update your event handlers:

```
private class ComboBoxListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        setCities(destinationBox.getSelectedIndex(), 
                  originBox.getSelectedIndex());
        updateDistanceText();
    }
}

private class RadioButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == kilometersRadioButton) {
            distanceLabel.setText("Distance (kilometers):");
            avgspeedLabel.setText("Avg. Speed (kph): ");
            setKm(true);
        } else if (event.getSource() == milesRadioButton) {
            distanceLabel.setText("Distance (miles): ");
            avgspeedLabel.setText("Avg. Speed (mph): ");
            setKm(false);
        }
        updateDistanceText();
    }
}
```

**EDIT** If you don't want to use techniques you haven't learned yet, you can use some copy-pasting... in general it's bad practice to have the same code at multiple places, because changing it is a pain, but for illustrative purposes, I'll do it anyway:

```
private class ComboBoxListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int selectedRow = destinationBox.getSelectedIndex();
        int selectedCol = originBox.getSelectedIndex();

        String text = fileData[selectedRow+1][selectedColumn+1];

        if (kilometersRadioButton.isSelected()) {
            text = String.valueOf(
                     MetricConverter.milesToKilometers(Double.valueOf(text)));
        }

        distanceText.setText(text);        
    }
}

private class RadioButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
        int selectedRow = destinationBox.getSelectedIndex();
        int selectedCol = originBox.getSelectedIndex();

        String text = fileData[selectedRow+1][selectedColumn+1];

        if (event.getSource() == kilometersRadioButton) {
            distanceLabel.setText("Distance (kilometers):");
            avgspeedLabel.setText("Avg. Speeg (kph): ");  

            text = String.valueOf(
                     MetricConverter.milesToKilometers(Double.valueOf(text)));
        } else if (event.getSource() == milesRadioButton) {
            distanceLabel.setText("Distance (miles): ");
            avgspeedLabel.setText("Avg. Speeg (mph): ");
        }

        distanceText.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand this, however I have yet to actually learn it in this way. I want to act within the knowledge we have in the course. Is there way using what I have?

Comment: @RandyB. Not really. As I described, you need to know both the state of the comboboxes and the radiobuttons in order to update your textfield.

Comment: distanceText.setText(fileData[selectedRow + 1][selectedCol + 1]); doesn't select the information we're looking for?

Comment: @RandyB. Not if the 'kilometers' radiobutton is selected. You might want to copy the code from my function `updateDistanceText`, replace `row` by `selectedRow`, `column` by `selectedColumn`, and `inKm` by `kilometersRadioButton.isSelected()`

Comment: Okay, this works then, but now the program doesn't have the default distanceText.setText(fileData[selectedRow +1][selectedCol + 1] on startup. I have to click one of the combobox choices for it to initiate. Why would it do this?

Comment: @RandyB. That shouldn't be the case... I don't know what you did exactly, but I updated my answer to show what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

Since your methods are static you can call directly by `Classname.methodName();`

If you want to store in String you can do something like this:

```
String str = String.valueOf(MetricConverter.kilometersToMiles( kilometers));
```

Comment: So it should be distanceText.valueOf(MetricConverter.kilometersToMiles(kilometers)); ?

Answer (score 0):

just:

```
distanceText.setText(String.valueOf(MetricConverter.milesToKilometers(fileData[selectedRow + 1][selectedCol + 1])));
```

or for miles:

```
distanceText.setText(String.valueOf(MetricConverter.kilometersToMiles(fileData[selectedRow + 1][selectedCol + 1])));
```

That works of course only if fileData contains double values.

Comment: fileData is from a .txt file. What would I do then?

Comment: convert the String to a Double

Comment: I don't seem to be getting this. The comboBox selected options are the city names. So if I convert the array itself to a double, that creates problems. I need to only create the distance number in the .txt file into a double from the selection of the two locations in the comboboxes